# Node.js as a long polling client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a node.js server that is actually a relay to another server. The node.js server must be able to long poll the other server and parse an xml response that is returned.

Any recommendations on this type of implementation? What library can I use to long poll this server?

Just to explain further details, there will be client connecting to the node server via socket.io. Once the node server receives and parses the xml response from the other server, it will emit and event for the client.

Comment: I don't quite get the problem. You want to poll some server. What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Right now, we have a JavaScript web application that long polls a service using POX. We do not have control over the service or its implementation. It only support long polling. The main problem we are facing is with cross domain requests in IE. We have to support IE7-9. It would be nice to simplify the UI with a library like Socket.IO that has transport fall backs that support cross domain request in IE and let node.js relay and do the long polling to the final service.

Answer (score 2):

i believe you are defeating the purpose / functionality provided by node.js , node.js will help you with long polling and it doesnt ideally need to poll the other server. in this case the other server which provides the xml should also allow long polling.

why dont you implement the logic of xml response generation on node.js itself so that you atleast reduce the time getting from a different server

Comment: Chandra. I'm not sure I fully understand. My apologies.